# Is there any function to replace a variable in python string?

Tags: python, replace, str-replace

#### I'm using python 3 and I just want to use only an efficient and effective single line of code for the following problem.

Suppose, I have a word and it has multiple combinations. I want to replace all the combinations with an efficient single line of code. 
For example,

```py
s2 = 'Hello Donald. DONALD is playing with his son. His son loves to play with donald' 
s2.replace('Donald', 'John')
```

This replaces only *Donald* not *DONALD* and *donald*.

How can I replace all combinations  ( *Donald*, *DONALD*, *donald* ) of *Donald* by *John*.

More explicitly :

```py
s3 = 'NO No nO no'
```

I can use

```py
s3.replace('NO', 'yes').replace('No', 'yes').replace('nO', 'yes').replace('no', 'yes')
```

But, the more combinations, the more replace functions.
How can I use replace function effectively and efficiently to replace all combinations *NO* by *yes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data_str = "No NO nO no".upper().replace('NO', 'YES')

print(data_str)

Comment: Thank you @krishna

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
re.sub("(?i)no","yes", "no No nO NO") # yes yes yes yes
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and in particular [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) in case-insensitive mode:

```
import re

re.sub('donald', 'john', 'DoNalD duck', flags=re.I)
# john duck
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to eliminate possible accents `ÁÀÃÂÇÉÊÍÕÓÔÚáàãâçéêíõóôú` you can first 'normalize' the char as in this regex-free code golf example [When I grow up I want to be ASCII](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200576/when-i-grow-up-i-want-to-be-ascii).

Then proceed to make all chars 'upper' or 'lower' and replace the desired string element.